# What do you call the process of combining two words to create a new one?

Tags: single-word-requests, portmanteau-words

Two very well established examples I can think of are:

- [Guesstimate](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/guesstimate) (i.e. Guess + Estimate)
- [Chillax](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chillax?q=Chillax) (i.e. Chill + Relax)

I guess I am meaning the process where two words are artificially combined into one, rather than when two words are combined to describe a new concept or item (e.g. Hatstand or lamppost). I suppose the distinction is blurry, but is there a word nonetheless?

Comment: They're called *portmanteau* words. Here's the wiki : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau

Comment: mmm...great word, "portmanteau". So, what's the process called? Portmanteau-izing?

Comment: @Urbycoz: It's called *blending*.

Comment: It can also be called *contraction*.

Comment: *Guesstimate is an informal English contraction of guess and estimate* -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guesstimate

Comment: I don't know about you, but I call it creombination.

Comment: This question is a doublicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91115/synochimeranyms

Comment: @vtt Love it. But at least mine is vaguely legible.

Comment: Portmanteau used to be a popular piece of luggage that held quite a lot. Louis Carol coined the term to refer to "packing" two or more words together into a single word in order to describe all of these types of words he was creating for Wonderland. Some suggest he may have picked Portmanteau not just for its renowned packing power but because it itself was a portmanteau of the words "porter" and "manteau" (a word for cloak). The verb Louis Carol used for this process was, as you may have surmised, "packing," as in "packing portmanteaus."

Comment: @Autoresponder, What's it called when two distinct words that are commonly together are concatenated into a compound noun.  Not just partial phoneme/meaning blends, like `guesstimate` but just literally removing the space and/or hyphen.  {scratches head}  `Corn flakes` _can_ be `cornflakes` but as IIRC `oatmeal` is never `oat meal`.  `filename` is now acceptable.  (etc.)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In linguistics, a [blend word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_word) is a word formed from parts of two or more other words. The process is called *blending* and the result is a *blend word*.

A [portmanteau word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) typically combines both sounds and meanings, as in *smog*, coined by blending *smoke and fog*. More generally, it may refer to any term or phrase that combines two or more meanings, for instance, the term "wurly" when describing hair that is both *wavy* and *curly*.

The word "portmanteau" was first used in this context by Lewis Carroll in the book *Through the Looking-Glass* (1871).

I'm not entirely sure if there is a technical distinction between *portmanteaus* and *blends* or if the latter is a hypernym of the former. There is some suggestion that portmanteaux specifically combine the beginning of the first word and the ending of the second. But I've been unable to confirm the validity of this distinction and I've found that they're mostly used interchangeably. Any information on this matter is welcome.

P.S. ELU has tags for both these terms: [portmanteau-words](/questions/tagged/portmanteau-words), [blend-words](/questions/tagged/blend-words).

Comment: A *blend* is normally made from word that would normally appear together, for example 'simcast' from 'simultaneous broadcast', while a *portmanteau* is made from words connected by theme, as in the OPs *guesstimate* made from 'guess' and 'estimate'.

Comment: @RoaringFish Please see [this section] of Wikipedia's page for _blend_. It suggests that _simulcast_ is a portmanteau (and a type of blend). I've seen your theory mentioned elsewhere as well.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a specific word for creating a *[portmanteau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau)*, but one usually *coins* new worlds, so the best expression would be *coining portmanteaus.*

Comment: *Minting* is also sometimes used, although *coining* remains more popular.  Note that the noun *portamento* means “A gliding or passing continuously from one pitch to another, in singing, or in playing a violin or similar instrument.”, which begs for a more musical verb to show the *portamento* in one’s *newly minted portmanteaux.* :)

Comment: @tchrist: Why not *compose*?

Comment: @JonPurdy Well sure, you could. I do find *compose* to be “fancier” word than *coin* or *mint*, and one that has quite differing connotations besides.

Comment: "I don't think there is a specific word..." Oh, come on, the answer is right there in the question. How about to *coinmanteau*? Or perhaps, following the word @tchrist mentioned, to *portminteau*.

Answer (score 0):

The examples in the question are not compounds in the usual sense, since in each case one of the words is incomplete. I agree with SF that they are portmanteau words. ("Portmanteau" originally means "suitcase". It was common in England in Lewis Carroll's time. As Humpty Dumpty explains to Alice, "You see it's like a portmanteau—there are two meanings packed up into one word." See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau#Origin.)

- **guesstimate**: The coda of "guess" and the first syllable of "estimate" are pronounced the same, /εs/. In this word they are merged: pronounced only once (not "guess-estimate"), and the "ess" of "guess" is all that's written. You could say that those identical parts of the two words overlap in the portmanteau.
- **chillax**: The first syllable of "relax" is completely gone here: we just have "chill" + "-lax". The only overlap is the /l/, and again it is written as in the first word.

Answer (score -2):

I call it **[compounding](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compounding)**, as it produces a compound word.

See Noun 2 under compound here http://www.thefreedictionary.com/compounding:

> Linguistics A word that consists either of two or more elements that are independent words, such as loudspeaker, baby-sit, or high school, or of specially modified combining forms of words, such as Greek philosophia, from philo-, "loving," and sophia, "wisdom."

Comment: -1. Compounding is exactly what this isn’t. Compounding is even specifically mentioned in the question (‘hatstand’, ‘lamppost’) as not what the asker is looking for. Compounding operates on entire words (sometimes in special compounding forms, but still entire words), while blending cuts words into pieces and mashes them together across morphemes and even phonemes.