# Is there a distinct term for acronyms with multi-letter parts?

Tags: terminology, abbreviations, acronyms, initialisms

Is there a distinct term for acronyms with multi-letter parts, particularly in title case?

My motivating examples are:

- **Conventions**: [BlizzCon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlizzCon), [NyCon II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/14th_World_Science_Fiction_Convention), [WonderCon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WonderCon) (nee *Wonder*ful World of Comics *Con*vention),  etc.
- **National * Months**: [NaNoWriMo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Novel_Writing_Month) (National Novel Writing Month), [NaBloPoMo](http://nablopomoguideunofficial.blogspot.com/), [NaSoAlMo](http://nasoalmo.org/), and other [timed artistic challenges](http://www.wikiwrimo.org/wiki/List_of_timed_artistic_challenges).

Technical linguistic terms like "clipping compounds" are acceptable parts of answers, but I think this has already been covered on ELU[[1](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/294183/207698)][[2](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/193830/207698)], and I'm not really looking for the linguistics answer. I'm really interested in popular **jargons or slangs** for this kind of naming from any groups (current or historical) that have done it. For example, in computer programming culture the jargon for the similar practice of textWithCapsAndNoSpaces is called "camel case."

Both "_Con" and "Na__Mo" seem to be meme-like, almost like [snoclone](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/snowclone) "phrasal templates." They both use the same partial-word, initial caps (ParWorInCap!) style of abbreviation.

**Does this style of naming itself have a name**?

Research:

I know that *abbreviations*, *contractions*, *acronyms*, and *initialisms* are already much discussed on ELU and elsewhere, and (non)distinctions are sometimes contested. To sum up common distinctions:

- **abbreviations** are any shortening of a word
  (Dr. <- Doctor)

  1. **contractions** are abbreviations that combine words by ommitting first/last
     (don't <- do not)
  2. **apocopations** are abbreviations that drop the end from a single word or separate words in a phrase [[*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_apocopations)]
     (photo <- photograph)
     (po-mo <- post-modern)
  3. **acronyms** are abbreviations from each initial letter or letters

     - ...each initial letter:
       (NASA <- National Aeronautics and Space Administration)

       - **initialisms** are acronyms in which letters are pronounced:
         (NSA <- National Security Agency)
     - ...initial letter groups, sometimes called *clipping compounds* [[*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/294183/207698)][[**](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/193830/207698)]:
       (Nabisco <- *Na*tional *Bi*scuit *Co*mpany)
       (ampersand <- *an*d *per* *s*e *and*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are known as [camel case](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/camel-case) words or abbreviations (at least, they are in the software industry).

[Wikipedia: Camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)