# Looking for a word that describes the merger of two words, is this an example of Portmanteau?

Tags: meaning, portmanteau-words, mergers, blending

This is slightly awkward to explain, so I will be as clear as possible. I am aware of what a *portmanteau* is, as you will see below, but I am unsure if my examples classify as such.

I'm looking to find out if there is a word similar to the term *portmanteau* but for when you join two words where the **last syllable/sound of the first word** is the same as the **first syllable/sound of the second word**. The spelling is often the same on the end of word one and start of word two, but not always.

Some examples of what I am trying to explain are as follows:

- Murderotica (murder + erotica)
- Disconnecktie (disconnect + neck tie)
- Bayonetwork (bayonet + network)
- Morgan Freemango (Morgan Freeman + mango)
- Typicalculation (typical + calculation)

Are these still examples of *portmanteau* or something else? By the definition of *portmanteau* and examples I think they aren't.

> A portmanteau word **fuses** both the **sounds** and the **meanings** of its components, as in *smog,* coined by **blending** *smoke* and *fog,* or *motel,* from *motor* and *hotel.* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau))

The reason I assume my examples are not *portmanteaux* is that both my words remain "whole" to a certain extent and can still be made out. In a stereotypical *portmanteau* parts of each original word are lost.

Comment: As you (and Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau ) observe, a portmanteau word fuses both the sounds *and* the meanings of its components. Do your merged words have a meaning of their own? What *is* a Morgan Freemango, what does one *do* with a disconnecktie?

Comment: @Spagirl They are nonsensical word play in reality. Some of the examples are song titles for an album I own. The others are answers in a gameshow quiz where we give a clue to each half of the word and the contestant must work out the joined word we have created

Comment: THB, I'm not sure in that case that they qualify as word play https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_play , if all that links the words is that one ends in the letters another begins in. That's just overlapping words.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do you call the process of combining two words to create a new one?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91306/what-do-you-call-the-process-of-combining-two-words-to-create-a-new-one)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - not a duplicate, OP knows the term  portmanteau, but is asking whether  it may be applied to the terms cited aboce.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I would agree with JOSH here as I am aware of what a portmanteau is and explain why I think my examples are different to my understanding of portmanteau. I have renamed the questions with "Is this a portmanteau?" to add clarity to this question and distinguish it from the question linked

Comment: Taking the idea of overlapping words, perhaps you could extrapolate from the language around Venn diagrams. After all, what you essentially have is two sets of letters with a subset of letters that are common to both. Perhaps *intersecting words* would do. Or as Venn called his diagrams "Eulerian Circles" after Euler, perhaps these can be Eulerian words, or Venn words, Set-words?

Comment: @spagirl I like your thinking here. We could almost create a new term for these words that overlap. I really love the term "Eulerian Word" but would that make sense, as I thought Eulerian was in essence "to use every point/edge at least once". (may be a bad understanding on my part)

Comment: @TomK89 I'll be honest, I know nothing of Euler at all! But I do think the lack of meaning of the resultant letter string is very much fundamental. You aren't creating 'words', You are creating an answer to a puzzle in the same way that 192016 would be the answer if you gave clues to the years 1920 and 2016. Its an answer but that's its only meaning.

Comment: @spagirl I have the PERFECT term for this... Venn Diagrammar!!

Comment: round of applause :)

Comment: That's not **the** definition of 'portmanteau'. It's one of several overlapping/conflicting definitions.

Comment: Some of your examples don't seem to have any meaning outside of puzzle context, but if you did form a meaningful word in that manner it would be a portmanteau, but part of a subset of portmanteaus meeting your extra criteria. I don't have a word for the subset.

Answer (score 1):

An "[overlapping blend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_word#Overlapping_blends)" is the most specific term I can find for this.