# Do these words have a name?

Tags: meaning

Crafty, Craf+tea= Craftea

Overwhelming, Over+whale+ming= Overwhaleming

cutie, Cu+tea= Cutea

Comment: These are probably [portmanteaus](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/portmanteau), but it [depends on what the mean.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/358613/looking-for-a-word-that-describes-the-merger-of-two-words-is-this-an-example-of)

Comment: @jejorda2 I don't think that's what they mean. 'Overwhaleming' isn't really a portmanteau because it isn't actually a word. I think they're talking about the homonymity of them.

Comment: ...although they aren't really homonyms (see comments below on Chris H's answer).

Comment: @Shasca where is this from? a crossword? We need context!

Comment: Since all three examples are not words as the title asks, they are puns. Many a long-winded joke sets up such puns through twists: Kicks are for Trids (from Trix are for kids), Mairzy Doats (sings like 'Mares eat oats'), and Spoonerisms (Are you nucking futs?).

Comment: As suggested in an answer in the linked question, I think a good word for this is "oronym"  *A string of words or phrase that sounds the same as another string of words or phrase but is spelt differently; e.g. ice cream and I scream.*

Answer (score 1):

In cryptic crosswords [*soundalike*](https://www.theguardian.com/crosswords/crossword-blog/2011/dec/08/cryptic-crosswords-for-beginners-soundalikes) is used for clues resulting in homophones.

The running together of two words to form the answer is known as a [*charade*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptic_crossword).

When both are used at the same time it would be logical to call this a *soundalike charade*, but this isn't standard. Of course as the concept of *sounds like* or *soundalike* is an important one in the game of charades, the whole construction could just be called a charade.

Comment: Are they homonyms? or does that only count for real words?

Comment: @marcellothearcane while *homonym* does have a secondary definition that means "sounds like", *homo**phone*** is the more common term.  Even that is usually reserved for 1:1 word<->word matches.  I'd be willing to use the adjective "homophonous" to describe two phrases that sound the same, though this may not be standard or correct.  Even that doesn't really fit the OP's examples (for the last, *queue+tea* is homophonous to *cutie*, but *Cu* is normally pronounced "copper"; *craf* in the first isn't a word, and *craft+tea* duplicates the *t* so doesn't work either)

Comment: ... the last example using a chemical symbol was what made me think of crosswords

Comment: If some of the elements were presented as pictures (a teapot, a whale) you could call them rebus puzzles.